# Chrome Extension "Object reference chain is too long" accessing currently selected element in dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Im creating a new dev tools pane for my Chrome extension. I need access to the html element selected in the Elements tab.

In manifest.json:

```
"devtools_page": "src/ui/devtools.html"
```

In devtools.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>Dev tools</title>
    <script type="module" src="./devtools.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In devtools.js:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane(
  "My panel",
  function (sidebar) {
    sidebar.setPage("src/ui/devtools-panel.html");
  }
);
```

In devtools-panel.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <script type="module" src="./devtools-panel.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>devtools-panel.html</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

In devtools-panel.js:

```
function logSelectedElementClassList() {
  chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("$0.classList", function (elem, err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(elem);
  });
}
logSelectedElementClassList();

chrome.devtools.panels.elements.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function () {
  logSelectedElementClassList();
});
```

So far this has worked. I have a new pane, and if I right click and inspect where it says "devtools-panel.html" I can see the currently selected element's classList is logged out and this updates when I select a different element in the normal dev tools.

[image]

However If I change the eval function to `$0` so that the entire selected element is used not just it's classList then I get an error:

```
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("$0", function (elem, err) {
```

> Object reference chain is too long evaluateGlobal @ sdk.js:1

> Extension server error: Inspector protocol error: Object reference chain is too long

```
{
  code: "E_PROTOCOLERROR",
  description: "Inspector protocol error: %s",
  details: ["Object reference chain is too long"]
}
```

Comment: DOM elements aren't serializable so you won't be able to pass it back. You can only use it inside the evaluated code and pass back its serializable (per JSON algorithm) properties.